# Fine tuning MariaDB grants to allow user to create database but not new users

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have the following initialization script:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'developer'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'devpassword1';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON *.* TO 'developer'@'%'; 
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'maintainer'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'maintainerpw1';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON *.* TO 'maintainer'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

which I mount to a docker container running `mariadb` using the volume mounts in a `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.7.3
    container_name: sql-db
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb/init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

### Requirements

I am looking to grant `developer` and `maintainer` most of R/W grants but they MAY NOT create new users. That should be possible only via `admin` user.

### Trials

I tried adding `CREATE USER` to both the `maintainer`/`developer` users  and it works which what I do not wish to have.

This was possible by doing:

```bash
docker exec -it sql-db mariadb -u developer -p
```

```bash
docker exec -it sql-db mariadb -u maintainer -p
```

and in both cases `CREATE USER dummy1@'%'` actually creates the user.
Is there a fine tuning possible for mariadb Grants on user to let them create databases but not users?

Answer (score 1):

The creation of [users](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/) requires `insert` privileges on `mysql.global_priv`. The restriction to avoid this privilege is hard without negative grants (coming sometime in the near future with [MDEV-14443](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14443)). This is because a `*.*` privileged is needed to create arbitrary databases (unless you want to namespace restrict the database to a non-`mysql` prefix `grant all on u_*.* to maintainer`).

What you can do is create a procedure like `mysql.create_db` and

```
MariaDB [mysql]> create or replace procedure
    mysql.create_db(IN dbname VARCHAR(30))
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    execute immediate concat('create database ',dbname);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.013 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> call mysql.create_db('catdog');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> create role maintainer;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.005 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> grant execute on procedure mysql.create_db to maintainer;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.003 sec)
```

Though with containers you might be just able to create a database instance per DB and ignore the complexities of multiple databases together.